# Inserting data from one column from one table to another specific table column while ignoring duplicates

Tags: mysql

I want to insert column1 from table1 to column1 in table2. If the value at column1 in table2 already exists I don't want it to insert it.

Though, I found a question on here that is similar but with all the table columns/rows instead of just one, plus both tables have different schemas except for column1. Because of this, I thought this question would still be valid to post for a more specific answer for mysql newbies like me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Insert Table2( Column1 )
Select Column1
From Table1 As T1
Where Not Exists    (
                    Select 1
                    From Table2 As T2
                    Where T2.Column1 = T1.Column1
                    )
```